# Update 2 containers using Pjax

Tags: yii2, pjax

I'm working on a transport planner in Yii2.
The tasks are shown in a GridView. 
Above the GridView I have a navigation to go through the dates.

like so:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false]); ?>
        <ul id="planner_nav">
            <li>
                <?= Html::a('', ['planner/previous'], ['class' => 'btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left pull-left']) ?>
            </li>
            <li>
                <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', $session->get('date')), ['#'], ['class' => 'planner_date']); ?>
            </li>
            <li>
                <?= Html::a('', ['planner/next'], ['class' => 'btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right pull-right']) ?>
            </li>
        </ul>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

As you can see the current date is stored in a session.
The date is set using `DateTime()`.

In my `actionIndex` in the `Planner-model` I pass the datesession to the `PlannerSearch-model` like:

```
$dataProvider = $dataModel->data(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $session->get('datum'));
```

And then grab the session: `PlannerSearch::search($params, $date)`, and use the `$date` variable in my query.

Maybe a terrible way of doing things, but I'm still a Yii (mvc) beginner..

What I actually want to achieve, is to go through the dates and update both the planner navigation date (`.planner_date`) and the GridView in the `planner-view` with the tasks for that day.

Anyone who can help?

Comment: Maybe, but is this a correct way to do things? I'm a bit confused..

Comment: @GAMITG `public function actionPrevious()
    {
        $date = new Date();
        $date->setDate('previous');
        return $this->actionIndex();
    }` Can I do something like this?